# Having multiple SQL queries in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I tried creating sql objects but i dont get the code to work. 
It seems when i do second query my drop down menu breaks. I have some flaw in my sql object creation please help.

First query (used to do a drop down menu):

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT DISTINCT bsect, bname AS Name FROM database");
```

After that i try to use sql object for 2nd query (used to output text from the selected book in drop down menu):

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT
bsect, bname, bnum, cnum, vnum, vtext, MATCH(vtext) AGAINST (?) AS
relevance FROM kjv WHERE MATCH(vtext) AGAINST (?) AND bsect='O' ORDER
BY relevance DESC, bnum, cnum, vnum LIMIT 0,10")) {
```

Closing both queries:

```
$query->close();
$stmt->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start troubleshooting by running the MySQL queries directly against your database and see if you have any MySQL errors or if the output of the queries isn't what you expected.  If that looks good, then try logging the output of your PHP script.  Here's a recommended [logging framework for PHP](http://pear.php.net/package/Log).  Make sure error output is turned on.  After you have verified that both your queries and your PHP script are doing what is expected, then, and only then, should you start troubleshooting your view (the dropdown box and output text in your case).

If you have any other questions or need clarification, please let me know.

Also, a very simply sanity check is to look for syntax errors in your PHP script.  Syntax highlighting is a common feature of IDEs such as WebStorm, Eclipse, and Netbeans (look for any lines of code that have a red underline).